# How to display all Events from multiple Google Calendars

Tags: javascript, calendar

I have two calendar with events and I want to get both events at a time and display as per the sorted date and time (with day in words)

I'm already using this JavaScript method to display one calendar and now I have two calendars so I want to merger and display :

```
calendar1= "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<?php echo $cal_id1; ?>/events?key=<?php echo $apikey1; ?>";
calendar2= "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<?php echo $cal_id2; ?>/events?key=<?php echo $apikey2; ?>";

formatGoogleCalendar.init({
        calendarUrl:calendar1,calendar2,
        past: false,
        upcoming: true,
        pastTopN: 5,
        upcomingTopN: 7,
        itemsTagName: 'li',
        upcomingSelector: '#events-upcoming',
        pastSelector: '#events-past',
        upcomingHeading: '<div id="myDIV" class="header"><font style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;'+digitdt+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><h2 style="margin:5px">Upcoming To Do List<font style="float:right; font-family:Digital-7; font-size:28pt;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Time&nbsp;'+digitxt+'</font></h2></div>',
        pastHeading: '',
        format: ['<font style="color:#f44336; font-weight: bold; font-size: 28pt;">☞</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>', '*date*', '</strong>:<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ', '*summary*', ' &mdash; ', '*description*', ' in ', '*location*']
      });
```

Can I pass 2 calendar urls and get it display like this?
              calendarUrl:calendar1,calendar2,
Please Help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution to merge multiple calendar in a simple manner and get all the events in one view as per the date/time. Following is the code I have used.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="FormatGoogleCalendar-master/dist/format-google-calendar.js"></script>
<!-- FormatGoogleCalendar Javascript file -->
<script src="FormatGoogleCalendar-master/dist/format-google-calendar.min.js"></script>

<script>  

//declare calendar urls with calendar id and api key
var calender1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/$cal_id/events?key=$apikey";


var calender2 = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/$cal_id/events?key=$apikey";


//store the calendar urls in an array


var cals = [calender1,calender2];


var CAL_ID ="";

//loop through and get each calendar urls


for (j = 0; j < cals.length; j++) {  


    CAL_ID = cals[j];            


      formatGoogleCalendar.init({
        calendarUrl:CAL_ID,
        past: false,
        upcoming: true,
        pastTopN: 0,
        upcomingTopN: 10,
        itemsTagName: 'li',
        upcomingSelector: '#events-upcoming',
        pastSelector: '#events-past',
        upcomingHeading: 'Upcoming Events',
        pastHeading: '',
        format: ['<font style="color:#f44336; font-weight: bold; font-size: 28pt;">☞</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>', '*date*', '</strong>:<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ', '*summary*', ' &mdash; ', '*description*', ' in ', '*location*']
      }); 
}
  </script>
```

Hope that this may help others as well.